# Changing machine's IP address after deploy phase for MaaS

Tags: networking, server, maas

Once we have deployed the machine using MaaS, the machine's interface cannot be edited anymore.
Is there a way to change the IP of the machine after we deploy it using MaaS and still ensure MaaS is aware of the new IP?

Answer (score 0):

on action, set it "mark broken", change ip, then "mark fixed", hopefully it fix the problem!

Comment: No, after rebooting the IP address isn't propagated to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the nic can not be controlled by cloudinit after deploy, the ip in maas is just an item in database.

So I disable the cloudinit conf file in /etc/netplan, then add new conf. The ip in maas updated automatically after that (maas 3).